# Medium term scheduler

Tags: operating-system

I have read in **Galvin book of operating system** about the Medium term scheduler.

It was written that:
Sometimes, it is advantageous to swap out the process when it is not executing[waiting for I/O or waiting for CPU] in order to decrease the degree of multiprogramming.
Also, we get more amount of physical memory which makes the execution of other process faster by decreasing the number of page faults[as we have more memory].

So, its the work of medium term scheduler to swap out & swap in partially executed process.

But My question is: **Does the work of medium term scheduler is really important in scenarios where we have plenty of available physical/main memory?**

Comment: Modern operating systems do not _swap out_ entire processes as they did back in 1980. Perhaps you need a newer book? Be sure to find one that mentions [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

Answer (score 2):

The use of medium term scheduler is to improve multiprogramming by allowing multiple processes to reside in main memory by swapping out processes that are waiting (need I/O) or low priority processes and swapping in other processes that were in ready queue.
So you can see that we requied medium term scheduler when we have limited memory. This swapping in and out operation does not take place when we are running a single small program and have large  memory.

Similary if we are running multiple programs and we have very large memory(larger than the size of all processes plus addition space for other requirements) then medium term scheduler is not needed. Modern operating systems use paging so instead of swapping processes they swap pages in and out of memory.It is same as a system with very large memory(infinite) would not suffer from page faults.

Answer (score 0):

Medium term scheduling is part of the swapping. It removes the processes from the memory. It reduces the degree of multiprogramming. The medium term scheduler is in-charge of handling the swapped out-processes.
TUTORIALS POINT
Simply Easy Learning Page 28
Running process may become suspended if it makes an I/O request. Suspended processes cannot make any progress towards completion. In this condition, to remove the process from memory and make space for other process, the suspended process is moved to the secondary storage. This process is called swapping, and the process is said to be swapped out or rolled out. Swapping may be necessary to improve the process mix.